# Time picker 4.2 and getting Edit Text

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, timepicker

i've been using upto 4.1.......

```
TimePicker tpClock = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tpClock);
View view  = tpClock.getChildAt(0);
EditText etHours = (EditText) ((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1);
```

this gets the Hour edittext so I can hide it.

This has been working really well

However it is not working for 4.2. How do I find what they have changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TimePicker view = new TimePicker(this);
View hour = view.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("hour", "id", "android"));
View input = hour.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android"));
// then you can do this
input.setClickable(false);
input.setFocusable(false);
// or this
input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/TimePicker.java/?v=source

Should be able to find the view there

Comment: thanks, i'm now trying to get to the xml layout .time_picker i've tried using the search but just end up back to where you sent me. Really annoying